# check palindrome through recursion c++

Tags: c++, recursion

```
bool palindrome(char arr[],int size){
    if(size<=1){
        return true;
    }
    if(*(arr)==*(arr+size-1)){
        bool small_ans=palindrome(arr+1,size-2);
        return small_ans;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How efficient is this code for checking palindrome ??

Comment: Efficient as in runtime or space efficient?

Comment: Runtime as well as Space..!

Comment: Because of the recursion it consumes `O(n/2)` space and `O(n/2)` time.

Comment: `return size <= 1 || (arr[0] == arr]size-1] && palindrome(arr+1, size-2));`

Comment: Is this an assignment that requires the use of recursion? 'Cause recursion is really not the way to go here.

Comment: @PeteBecker YES it was asked to solve this using recursion

Comment: Answer is going to be opinion based. In most cases a iterative algorithm will be more speed efficient then a recursive one since it doesn't involve the call overhead. For a recursive solution the idea looks good.

Comment: @AGNIVASHIL -- you have my sympathy. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker I concur

Comment: g++, clang++, and vc++ all transform the tail call into a loop, so this is very efficient. (Sadly enough, vc++ apparently doesn't optimize my "improved" version, which goes to show that you shouldn't blindly trust anyone's intuition - in particular your own.)

Answer (score 3):

There is compiler optimization called tailing recursion.

In your quite simple case compiler spotted that there is possibility to use this optimization. As a result it silently turn your code into iterative version:

https://godbolt.org/z/rsjaYhde6

```
palindrome(char*, int):
        cmp     esi, 1
        jle     .L4
        movsx   rax, esi
        sub     esi, 2
        shr     esi
        lea     rax, [rdi-1+rax]
        lea     edx, [rsi+1]
        add     rdx, rdi
        jmp     .L3
.L8:
        add     rdi, 1
        sub     rax, 1
        cmp     rdi, rdx
        je      .L4
.L3:
        movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rax]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rdi], cl
        je      .L8
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.L4:
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

Note:

- there is no `call` instruction needed in code which actually uses recursion
- label `.L8` is responsible for a loop which replaced recursion

Remember there is "[As-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)" so compiler can transom your code in may ways to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the recursive solution is often more elegant than iteration, but mostly needs more CPU time and memory space. The CPU has to put data on the stack every recursion.

Especially in this case, iteration seems more efficient in time and memory.

Try somthing like this:

```
bool palindrome(char arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[size-1-i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should probably only iterate through half of the string, right? Otherwise you are checking everything twice.

Comment: iterating upto size/2 right?

Comment: I have strong doubt about the _more elegant_ part. There's nothing good in recursion, here, IMO.

Comment: Indeed - iteration up to size/2 is enough